# Pass multiple inputs to my filter with angular

Tags: angularjs, arguments

I have an angular filter that takes an input string such as 'foo' and is supposed to break it down and add a second input to it, such as 'X'
should result in 'fXoXoX'

buuuut I'm super new at this, and I'm probably going about it all wrong.

here is what I have in my HTML:

```
   Input: <input ng-model='input'>
    <p></p>
    Delimiter: <input ng-model='delimiter'>
    <p>{{input, delimiter | tokenize}}</p>
```

here is what I have in my script.

```
 .filter('tokenize', function () {
    return function (value, value2) {
        if (angular.isString(value)) {
                function tknz (value, value2) {
                    var spV = value.split('');
                    var joiV = spV.join(value2)
                    return joiV;
                };

                return tknz(value,  value2);

        } else {
            return value;
```

I fear that I don't even know the syntax to pass multiple arguments to the filter in the HTML or otherwise, and I'm stuck googling and finding no answer to that.

Comment: was the posted answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass arguments to your pipe as

```
{{input | pipe:delimiter }}
```

which should be captured in your filter as

```
transform(input, delimiter) {}
```

Read more about creating custom pipes at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter